# Is there an option I can use to limit the number of times a cached resource is returned to clients in Nginx?

Tags: nginx, caching, cache-control, nginx-config

I have a scenario where I want to limit the number of times a file cached by Nginx is going to be served.

I've found options to limit the amount of memory or disk space or the amount of time the file is cached for, but I don't see anything about limiting the number of times a file gets served from the cache.

My idea is to serve the file at most 1,000 times then I want Nginx to query the backend again so that way if something changed it can update its caches. It would be much better this way than having to do 1,000 `GET`s (even if it happens with the cache `ETag`).

We could easily add HTTP headers to our requests, although there too I don't recall seeing anything that would reflect the concept of counting the number of requests to the cached data.

Comment: Do you have more context for why you want to do this? Would, for example, using your average download rate to calculate an expected amount of time be an option?

Comment: @Joe It's related to counting the number of times an ad gets accessed. There are other means for us to get the total count, but we would like to have a way to limit the total number we serve so we have a total count that doesn't go over what the paying customer paid for.